# Where did the user icons go?

Tags: user-profile

I've just upgraded to xenial xerus.

There's no ~/.local/share/icons... do I have to create it? Does it live somewhere else?

It ain't there and searches turn up nothing. I keep bookmarks to these places so I can easily create my own *.desktop files.

Comment: FYI I have the same OS version and the directory exist.

Comment: It definitely appears that the directory does not exist by default on a fresh installation of Ubuntu 16.04.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The location `~/.local/share/icons` is still a valid thing in 16.04, it's just usually not needed and therefore somebody decided not to create it by default. If you want to use this directory, simply create it.

However, user-specific `.desktop` files need to go to `~/.local/share/applications` instead to have an effect.

Comment: Yup, I already have a link for that too.  Thx! :-)